# Two Neumann eigenfunctions with parallel gradients along the boundary of a manifold

Tags: partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, laplacian, elliptic-operators

Let $(M, g)$ be a compact Riemannian $3$-manifold with boundary. Is it possible to exist two independent Neumann eigenfunctions $u, v \in C^{\infty}(M)$ associated to the same eigenvalue $\mu > 0$ of the Laplacian $\Delta_g$ and such that $\nabla u(p)$ and $\nabla v(p)$ are parallel for any $p \in \partial M$? It looks a rather strong condition to impose. Are there any examples?

This showed up in my research, so I appreciate any ideas or comments.